# Calculate the Derivative of Gradient Field of an Image

Tags: image-processing, discrete-signals, linear-algebra, finite-differences

I meet a confusing thing in image processing recently....

Assume the image $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, with its derivative (difference) matrix: $D^+ = \begin{bmatrix} D_h  \\ Dv \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{2n\times n}$ ($+$ means forward difference), also equal to $\nabla$. Therefore, it is natural to define the divergence: $\triangle = \nabla \cdot \nabla$.

I have seen some papers use $div = \triangle = D_h^-D_h^+ + D_v^-D_v^+ \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, where $-$ denotes the backward difference.

Here is my question: assume I want to calculate the $\frac{\partial\|\nabla x -p\|_2^2}{\partial x}$ where $p\in \mathbb{R}^{2n\times 1}$ is a vector not related to $x$, what is the result? I have seen some authors use $\nabla\cdot (\nabla x -p)$.

However, if writing the $\nabla$ as matrix form $D$ as I have introduced before, $D^T$ is exactly adjoint of gradient, not backward difference. Hence $-\triangle x$ would appear! So what is the right formula? Could anyone tell me?

Comment: What is p, and please specify dimensions of all the matrices and vectors

Comment: @Dspguysam Thanks for your advise. I have edited the question.

Comment: $\nabla x$ will be a vector of dimension 2n and you are subtracting that to a matrix $p$ of dimension 2nxn? Did I get that right?

Comment: @Dspguysam Yes, you are right. I have already marked the dimension of $p$.

Comment: a matrix times a vector will result in a vector, and you can only subtract or add  vectors of same dimension in a space, therefore $p$ should be a vector, not a matrix, and the dimension of "vector" $p$ should be the same as number of rows of $\nabla$, $p$ should be $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ not $\mathbb{R}^{2n*n}$

Comment: @Dspguysam Oh sorry, I make a mistake. The dimension of $p$ should be $2n \times 1$...

Comment: yes, i have given an answer now on this below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the expansion of the term below
$$\|\nabla x -p\|_2^2 = (\nabla x -p)^T(\nabla x -p)$$
$$\|\nabla x -p\|_2^2 = (x^T\nabla^T -p^T)(\nabla x -p)$$
 $$\|\nabla x -p\|_2^2 = (x^T\nabla^T\nabla x - x^T\nabla^T p  - p^T\nabla x +p^Tp)$$

Now consider the following basic definition:

$$\frac{\partial(A x)}{\partial x} = A^T$$
$$\frac{\partial(x^TA)}{\partial x} = A$$

Now applying the above two definitions together with the expansion of the objective above to differentiate the objective we have

$$\frac{\partial\|\nabla x -p\|_2^2}{\partial x} = 2\nabla^T\nabla x - 2\nabla^Tp$$

$$\frac{\partial\|\nabla x -p\|_2^2}{\partial x} = 2\nabla^T(\nabla x - p)$$

since $\nabla^T = \nabla$, therefore we have

$$\frac{\partial\|\nabla x -p\|_2^2}{\partial x} = 2\nabla(\nabla x - p)$$ the constant 2 is just a constant, so the result we have is consistent with the ones that authors are using, its simply a consequence of vector differentiation

Comment: The question is here:  where is the conclusion of  $\nabla^T = \nabla$? When we express it in matrix form, for example, let $D$ represents the forward difference, $D^T \neq D$ sinc $D_h^T \neq D_h$

Comment: $D^T$ is the adjoint of gradient. If you implement it in programming language, $D_h^T = -D^-_h$

Comment: For this to be a valid definition $\triangle = \nabla \cdot \nabla$, firstly $\nabla$should be a square matrix and is $\triangle$ should be positive semidefinite, in that case $\nabla^T = \nabla$

Comment: I agree. In mathematics this is valid. But how about changing the $\nabla$ to $D$? The things goes different.

Comment: this is all maths. According to the definition you provide D is not a square matrix, then it can never be substituted as $\nabla$ , which has to be a  square matrix, based on the definitions you provide as I explained above, If you want give me an objective function in terms of D that you want to differentiate with respect to x. We will have no problem doing it. Currently the objective is in terms of $\nabla$ for which the result is consistent. D and $\nabla$ have to have equal dimesnions first to be equated!

Comment: The gradient, or $\nabla$ is a linear operator which can be expressed as matrix. Or discard the matrix form first. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_gradient#Mathematics describes the definition. If $\nabla$ is square, then multiply it with $x$  creates $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$?

Comment: The definition of gradient of $ f : \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R} $ is $ \nabla f :  \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n} $. In case of scalar image it means that for an image with $ k l  $ pixels the gradient should be $ 2 k l $ pixels. Since each pixel is a function of 2 dimensions. So if you define the matrix that way I think things should be aligned.

Comment: @Royi That is true for the definition of gradient of $f$. Do you mean that the definition of matrix is wrong? Could you provide an example to express gradient as matrix?

Comment: The matrix form is an approximation by using the Finite Differences Method. Given you the kernel, there are many ways to apply it (Boundary conditions). Which is right? You will get the same answer, no single method works for everything. You need to adjust according to what you want to achieve.